# How to mount a Kerberized NFS filesystem in CoreOS?

Tags: nfs, kerberos, coreos

I'm trying to define a systemd mount using `cloud-config.yml` so that CoreOS mounts a kerberized file system at startup.

The filesystem provider has handed me the `krb5.conf` and `krb5.keytab` which I write to `/etc` folder using `write_files` section of `cloud-config.yml`.

This is my mount specification:

```
- name: mnt-backup.mount
  enable: true
  content: |
    [Mount]
    What=vid52590.nas1.lan:/vid52590
    Where=/mnt/backup
    Options=sec=krb5
    Type=nfs
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When the system tries to mount the nfs filesystem I get the following message though journalctl:

```
Sep 12 16:30:40 backend systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/backup...
Sep 12 16:30:40 backend systemd[1]: mnt-backup.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Sep 12 16:30:40 backend systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/backup.
Sep 12 16:30:40 backend systemd[1]: mnt-backup.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

I have tried issuing the command on the console like so:

```
sudo mount -o sec=krb5 vid52590.nas1.lan:/vid52590 /mnt/backup
```

Getting the following error:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting vid52590.nas1.lan:/vid52590
```

I have double checked that the krb5.keytab has been properly written byte by byte.

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this config? Thanks in advance!

When running:

```
kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab <principal>
```

The command returns but no response is shown. If I use an inexistent principal it says:

```
kinit: Keytab contains no suitable keys for <invalid_pricipal> while getting initial credentials
```

Comment: Does a manual kinit using the specified keytab file work?

Comment: What should the complete command be?

Comment: That will depend on the principal stored inside the keytab file. But you can check it with something like "klist -kt /etc/krb5.keytab". Then, "kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab <principal>"

Comment: I updated the question with the output of the command. No output at all with the right principal

Comment: No output at all is actually good. It means you were successfully able to retrieve a ticket with that keytab. You can view the ticket details with a "klist -ef" command.

Comment: Yep, seems that the ticket gets generated, so there should be no problem with the authorization, though the error message seems to be associated to a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it seems that nfs-utils package in coreos is built without kerberos support.
So the system is missing rpc.gssd which is essential for a kerberized nfs setup